# Aren't ASCII values of 'a' to 'z' consecutive from 97 to 122 irrespective of implementation? A good book says otherwise

Tags: c, char, ascii, portability

I see nothing wrong with the following program, and this being non-portable is really confusing to me. According to the book by Mike Banahan [(GBdirect C Book, Section 2.4.2)](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter2/integral_types.html), the following program is non-portable. Reason given is:

> Another example, perhaps. This will either print out the whole lower case alphabet, if your implementation has its characters stored consecutively, or something even more interesting if they aren't. C doesn't make many guarantees about the ordering of characters in internal form, so this program produces non-portable results!

So, in simple terms, can you explain me what's wrong with the below program? Aren't the ASCII values of characters same irrespective of implementation? I mean, value of 'a' is always 97 and that of 'b' is always 98; so why is getting the latter by adding 1 non-portable?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main(){
      char c;

      c = 'a';
      while(c <= 'z'){
              printf("value %d char %c\n", c, c);
              c = c+1;
      }

      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Yes, ASCII a-z is by definition consecutive.  What's implementation-dependent is whether ASCII is being used at all.

Comment: You can perfectly well have C-whatever implementation that uses EBCDIC, and there the alphabet is not consecutive.

Comment: As a side note: a portable way which does *not* rely on a particular encoding of the character set is to put the entire string `"abc..xyz"` inside the code and loop over that. (A further nitpick, then, could be "you are assuming the character code for `a` fits in a `char` variable!)

Comment: A wonky mainframe encoding from the past isn't exactly relevant anymore.  It is the 5 billion potential customers that have their own idea about what their alphabet looks like that will byte you in the rear end *today*.

Comment: Considering what @HansPassant points out, there isn't much use in thinking about ASCII either. It has been assimilated into many other character sets. The thing you have to know is which one you (or your users) are using. (Run `locale` in Linux or `chcp` in Windows.)

Answer (score 5):

C doesn't require ASCII encoding. It allows other encodings, some of which may not have letters represented by consecutive values.

An example is [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) where letters are not consecutive.

Note that the characters for digits are guaranteed by the C standard to always be consecutive (although they may not have values 48-57 as in ASCII).

Comment: "C doesn't guarantee ASCII encoding"--That's something new for me. Thanks. I had steadfastly assumed that in C, 'A' is 65, newline is 10 and so on :-(

Comment: @Meathead: correct. This is the source of much nitpicking (including by yours truly ), and while in reality it will not be an issue you are likely to run in to, it is important nevertheless to *always* keep it in mind. Note that your sample code used `c = 'a';` and *not* `c = 97;`

Comment: @Jongware Point noted, especially the one about "c=97". Thanks.

Comment: Java, on the other hand, requires Unicode (of which ASCII is a subset).